# Is this question better for Travel or Expats SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, expat-questions

> I'm an American citizen planning to go to Seoul as a tourist for a month or two, and, if I like it, enroll in a three-month Korean language course through one of the universities there (making a total stay of five months, more than the 90 days I can get visa-free).
>
> Once I'm in Seoul as a tourist, what are my options for extending my stay in order to take a language course? Do I need to apply for a visa? Can I do this in the country?

It involves a fairly short stay, involving some time as a tourist, but also a bit of studying and maybe a student visa, so I wasn't sure which site it would be better to ask on.

Answer (score 6):

It fits in Travel.SE indeed. Not in Expats.SE. The intention is tourism, short stays for courses are usually on-topic here and more of a recreational thing.

Comment: Any explanation?

Comment: It probably *could* fit Expats, too (I’m not over there, so I don’t know what they consider on- or off-topic), but of course, it is irrelevant to determine whether a question is on-topic on another site to determine whether it is off-topic here. Hence +1.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this question is a better fit for Expats. The root of the problem is that you want to convert a tourist visa into a temporary residence permit to **study** in a given country.

Answer (score 2):

It should be acceptable on both sites. Maybe it falls under the regulation governing short/tourism/visitor visa-free stays, maybe you need an entirely different document because you are staying longer than 90 days but this depends entirely on local law and the specifics of your situation and ultimately we can't really know without knowing the answer.